# In SSMS how do you check how much space an index takes on disk

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I can't find any context sensitive menu options on the index itself that will show me current disk utilization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just want to use a query to show this information. See this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316831/table-and-index-size-in-sql-server) for details.